# C++ inheritance and templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a List template.

I want to make a list of Jobs. However, I have different jobs when the only different thing is the function executeJob().

So I have a class Job:

```
class Job{...
...
public:
..
virtual SomeType executeJob() = 0;
}
```

So it's actually an abstract class and in the derived classes all the private fields are the same and it has the implementation for its own executeJob().

Lets say there are 2 different type of derived classes called `Job1` and `Job2` so I actually want my list to be able to have `Job1 objects` and `job2 Objects` as well.

My list is defined this way: `List<Job>`.

But in the ListNode c'tor I have this:

```
    listNode(const T& value) : value(new T(value)), prevNode(NULL),
    nextNode(NULL){}
```

and of course I have a problem with the line: `value(new T(value))` as it's an abstract class.
How do I solve it so I still can hold a list of both `Job1 and Job2 objects` and define it as `List<Job>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you can't take `T` in the constructor.

You need a templated constructor, that takes the real class. Then you will call the constructor on the type of the parameter.

If you don't have the type, and only pass around "Job", then you will have to switch to prototype based design with a virtual `clone()` method (instead of calling the constructor).

Edit: Since you are using `new`, I'm assuming that the `List<Job>` is a typo and you meant `List<Job*>`

Comment: instead of the typo, value could also be defined as "T* value;".  Yet another reason to use STL.

Comment: @stefaanv OK, then it's bad design. Pointer hiding is always bad.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a list containing different objects.

You could have a list of pointers to base class though.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that the other answers are not covering well is that when you have a templated class C and you instantiate that class with two different template types, for all practical purposes the compiler sees these as being two distinct classes, not one class instantiated in two ways.

The types are incompatible unless you take the suggestion provided of storing pointers to a base class in your list. This way, if B and D derive off of A, then you can store B*'s and D*'s in the list, but access them through an A*.